# pmAuto ModalPopupMode proper use or bug workaround

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm having problems using TApplication.ModalPopupMode=pmAuto and I was wondering if my problems were caused by my usage of pmAuto or a bug in delphi.

Simple use case:

- Form1(MainForm) and Form3 are permanent forms. (Created in the dpr)
- Form2 is created when needed and
  freed afterward.
- Form3 contains a TComboBox with X items.

Sequence of actions :

- Form1 create and show Form2 modal.
- Form2 show form3 modal.
- Close Form3
- Close and free Form2
- Show Form3 <---- The TComboBox now contains 0 items.

I use ComboBox as an example, but I guess any controls that saves information in the DestroyWnd procedure and restore it in the CreateWnd procedure isn't working right. I tested TListBox and it displays the same behavior too.

- Is it a known fact that one shouldn't mix permanent and temporary form when ModalPopupMode is pmAuto?
- If not, is there any known workaround for this problem?
- If it's a bug, is this fixed in more recent version of Delphi? (I'm using XE4)

Comment: I don't get it. `Form3` is a permanent form. So there is one instance of it always alive during the whole process, right? When it is being closed shall it hide or destroy itself? So when you show it again then there is a completely new instance of `Form3`, isn't it?

Comment: When it closes, Form3 only hides itself.  So when it is shown again, it's not a new instance. The only time Form3 is created is in the dpr `Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not really a bug, just a quirk in how the various windows interact with each other when dealing with modality.

When `Form3` is first created, `TComboBox.CreateWnd()` is called during DFM streaming.  When `Form3.ShowModal()` is called for the first time, `Form3` calls `RecreateWnd()` on itself if its `PopupMode` is `pmNone` and `Application.ModalPopupMode` is not `pmNone`.  OK, so `TComboBox.DestroyWnd()` gets called, saving the items, then `TComboBox.CreateWnd()` gets called, restoring the items.  Recreating the `TComboBox`'s window during `ShowModal()` is not ideal, but it works this time.

When `Form3.ShowModal()` is called the second time, `TComboBox.CreateWnd()` is called again **without** a previous call to `TComboBox.DestroyWnd()`!  Since the items have not been saved, they cannot be restored.  That is why the `TComboBox` is empty.

But why does this happen?  When `Form2` is freed, `Form3`'s window is still associated with `Form2`'s window.  The first call to `Form3.ShowModal` set `Form2`'s window as `Form3`'s parent/owner window.  When you close a `TForm`, it is merely hidden, its window still exists.  So, when `Form2` and `Form3` are closed, they still exist and are linked together, and then when `Form2` is destroyed, all of its child and owned windows get destroyed.  `TComboBox` receives a `WM_NCDESTROY` message, resetting its `Handle` to 0 without notifying the rest of its code that the window is being destroyed.  Thus, `TComboBox` does not have a chance to save its current items because `DestroyWnd()` is not called.  `DestroyWnd()` is called only when the VCL itself is destroying the window, not when the OS destroys it.

Now, how can you fix this?  You will have to destroy the `TComboBox`'s window, triggering its `DestroyWnd()` method, before freeing `Form2`.  The trick is that `TComboBox.DestroyWnd()` will save the items only if the `csRecreating` flag is enabled in the `TComboBox.ControlState` property.  There are a few different ways you can accomplish that:

1. call `TWinControl.UpdateRecreatingFlag()` and `TWinControl.DestroyHandle()` directly.  They are both `protected`, so you can use an accessor class to reach them:

   ```
   type
     TComboBoxAccess = class(TComboBox)
     end;

   Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
   try
     Form2.ShowModal;
   finally
     with TComboBoxAccess(Form3.ComboBox1) do
     begin
       UpdateRecreatingFlag(True);
       DestroyHandle;
       UpdateRecreatingFlag(False);
     end;
     Frm.Free;
   end;
   Form3.ShowModal;
   ```
2. call `TWinControl.RecreateWnd()` directly.  It is also `protected`, so you can use an accessor class to reach it:

   ```
   type
     TComboBoxAccess = class(TComboBox)
     end;

   Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
   try
     Form2.ShowModal;
   finally
     TComboBoxAccess(Form3.ComboBox1).RecreateWnd;
     Frm.Free;
   end;
   Form3.ShowModal;
   ```

   The `TComboBox` window is not actually be created until the next time it is needed, in the subsequent `ShowModal()`.
3. send the `TComboBox` window a `CM_DESTROYHANDLE` message and let `TWinControl` handle everything for you:

   ```
   Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
   try
     Form2.ShowModal;
   finally
     if Form3.ComboBox1.HandleAllocated then
       SendMessage(Form3.ComboBox1.Handle, CM_DESTROYHANDLE, 1, 0);
     Frm.Free;
   end;
   Form3.ShowModal;
   ```

   `CM_DESTROYHANDLE` is used internally by `TWinControl.DestroyHandle()` when destroying child windows.  When a `TWinControl` component receives that message, it calls `UpdateRecreatingFlag()` and `DestroyHandle()` on itself.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear in my question I already know "why" it happens. I came to the same conclusion as you. What I wanted to know was more about whether or not this is known/intended behavior or just a design mistake in the VCL. (i.e. should TComboBox/TListBox/etc save their info upon receiving WM_DESTROY and not csDestroying instead of on CM_DESTROYHANDLE?). This was an MVCE, but in the application I work on, manually going over all the controls of all the forms isn't something realistic.

Comment: What I retain from this is that pmAuto is, at best, unreliable with "permanent" forms. Still upvoted for thorough research. But unless someone brings more information to the table, we'll probably just revert to pmNone and live with the Z-order problem, stick with "the devil you know". As a curiosity, which version of delphi did you reproduce it with?

Comment: The VCL tries not to persist window data unless it knows the data will be needed later. Thus why `DestroyWnd()` looks for `csRecreating`. In `WM_(NC)DESTROY` themselves, without that flag, the VCL does not know why the window is being destroyed or if a new window will replace it afterwards. Having those messages persist window data would be a waste of memory without context to warrant it. That being said, the whole `DestroyWnd/CreateWnd` persistence model predates `(Modal)PopupMode`, so it is a little dated when faced with the various ways that windows gets destroyed in modern API models.

Comment: I reproduced it with XE2.  And it is not just `pmAuto` that is affected by this. The core problem exists in `TCustomForm.CreateParams()` itself for any combination of `PopupMode`+`ModalPopupMode`, as they all try to set a suitable parent window for purposes of fixing z-ordering. It comes down to the assignment of the `TCreateParams.WndParent` field, which is what is setting `Form2` as `Form3`'s parent window so `Form3` cannot ever appear behind `Form2`, unless the `TApplication` window, or other `TForm` window, is set as the `WndParent`.

Comment: I wish I could apply this comment to the question and both answers. Thank you so much. Eight years later and it still helps others. The behavior still occurs in 11.3.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Remy's excellent answer I implemented something that fixes these issues in the whole application. You will need to descend all your modal forms from a custom TForm descendant - TMyModalForm in my example (which, IMO, is always a good practice anyway). All modal forms in my application descend from this. Please notice that I also set PopupMode to pmAuto in CreateParams() before calling the inherited method. This prevents the z-order problem when showing modal windows, but also causes the window handle problem described in your question.  Also, I just broadcast the CM_DESTROYHANDLE if action is caHide. This skips an unnecessary notification for MDI child windows and modal windows which are destroyed on close.
BTW, for future reference, this issue still exists in Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo.

```
type
  TMyModalForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

procedure TMyModalForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  Msg: TMessage;
begin
  inherited DoClose(Action);
  if Action = caHide then
  begin
    FillChar(Msg, SizeOf(Msg), 0);
    Msg.Msg := CM_DESTROYHANDLE;
    Msg.WParam := 1;
    Broadcast(Msg);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyModalForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  PopupMode := pmAuto;
  inherited;
end;

end;
```

Comment: Instead of broadcasting `CM_DESTROYHANDLE` manually, it would be simpler to have the Form call `RecreateWnd()` on itself, and let that broadcast `CM_DESTROYHANDLE` to all child controls: `procedure TMyModalForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); begin inherited DoClose(Action); if Action = caHide then RecreateWnd; end;`

Comment: Yes, simpler in terms of less lines of code, but a longer execution path to accomplish the same thing.