# Is it possible to get the origin of a call to SetWindowPos?

Tags: winapi

We've had an issue reported about our application "freezing". After investigation, what happens is, our main form ends up `WS_EX_TOPMOST`, so when a modal form is shown, it ends up being shown behind our main form which then appears to be frozen.

Considering we've never set our form as TOPMOST, our working assumption at the moment is that another application is, mistakenly or not, setting our application's mainform as TOPMOST through:

```
SetWindowPos(OurFormHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE)
```

So how would one identify the guilty party?

I'll post the method I came up with, just wondering if there is something more reliable...

Comment: Surely if your modal form is created with the correct popup parent (aka window owner) then it should always be above your main form

Comment: We tried that, didn't go so well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099167/pmauto-modalpopupmode-proper-use-or-bug-workaround.  And beside, we'd still don't want our application TOPMOST.

Comment: I get that you don't want your application to be top most. But it's a mistake not to set the popup parent correctly.

Comment: Putting yourself behind a topmost window [also makes you topmost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170914-00/?p=97025).

Comment: But setting the popup parent properly breaks Delphi's VCL...  So I'd be tempted to say that, while using the VCL, it's a mistake to set the popup parent properly.

Comment: No, it doesn't break the VCL

Comment: @RaymondChen I did read your blog in my research. Thing is, calls to SetWindowPos are pretty scarce in our codebase as they are pretty much all taken care of by our framework.  And we didn't change version of our framework in a few year. This is why we suspect a 3rd party. Then again, so far, we've only had report of the problem in Windows 10 (we still have some Win7 in the wild). So maybe it's the latest Windows update that is causing issues with our framework... I can only speculate at this point.

Comment: @KenBourassa not only does it not break the VCL, but the VCL even has its own [`PopupParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.PopupParent) property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And said VCL loses the content of combobox, listbox (and memo?) in some real world use case. And yeah... You provided some work around in the linked question. But that would be a few 1000s LOC workaround for our project. All of that because the VCL doesn't quite behave properly when a form's parent window is destroyed. I mean, sure, not all use case fail...  But some sure do.

Comment: Having a modal window with the popup parent incorrectly set is as bad as it gets. The modal window gets stuck behind other windows.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, a call to `SetWindowPos` doesn't returns until the process owning the target window's process the `WM_WindowPosChanging` and `WM_WindowPosChanged` message.

During the WM_WindowPosChanging, it doesn't seem possible to know if the form will become topmost, much less prevent it (hwndInsertAfter isn't HWND_TOPMOST anymore, and doesn't even refer a TOPMOST window). So there isn't much we can do here as we don't know if we're in trouble.

However, when WM_WindowPosChanged is processed, the WS_EX_TOPMOST style has been applied to the window's style. So by that point, you know you've been set topmost.

So now... How could we make a "guilty process" stand out of the crowd? Well,  I did mention `SetWindowPos` doesn't return until WM_WindowPosChanged is done processing.  So, if we were to, lets say, sleep for 10 seconds while processing WM_WindowPosChanged, the calling process would become unresponsive!

At that point, we can `EnumWindows`and test if they are `IsHungAppWindow` and retrieve the name of the applications they belong to.

Oh... and we'll still collect a callstack, in case this is actually the result of some wild side-effect in our code and not a "rogue application".

## Limitations

Obviously, if `SetWindowPos` is called from a windowless thread, that technique won't work. It might also have a few false positive.

Some of this is most likely working "by implementation" rather than "by design".